# How to add delay between adding classes to html elements in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate this section of my portfolio page:

[image]

I would like for each of those 5 bars to light up one at a time.

Here are is the relevant code for this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 skill-item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2"><i class="devicon-html5-plain-wordmark"></i></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 skill-bar">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2 skill-rank-inactive"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 skill-rank-inactive"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 skill-rank-inactive"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 skill-rank-inactive"></div>                                    
                            <div class="col-lg-2 skill-rank-inactive"></div>                                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 skill-level">
                        HTML5
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.skill-rank-inactive {
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    height: 3vh;
    transition: all 2s;
}

#back-end { 
    .skill-rank-active {
        background: $green;
        border: 2px solid white;
        height: 3vh;
    }

    i {
        color: $green;
    }
}

#front-end {
    .skill-rank-active {
        background: $blue-bright;
        border: 2px solid white;
        height: 3vh;
        transition: all 2s;
    }

    i {
        color: $blue-bright;
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#skills-page').bind('inview', function() {
    $('.skill-rank-inactive').addClass('skill-rank-active');
    $('.skill-rank-inactive').removeClass('skill-rank-inactive');
});
```

Is there a way to add 500ms delay between the transition of each "skill-rank" on the page? There would be multiple skills such as PHP, CSS, etc... I'd like for each skill to start at the same time, ie. the first rank for each skill starts then 500ms the next rank all the way up.

Comment: CSS animation seems like a better choice.

Comment: Will that allow me to delay each block separately?

Comment: you should look at queuing animations https://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay)

Comment: Since blocks never light up at the same time, you actually only need one extra element that blinks on top of each block in turn! Saves the headache of queuing animations.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to take the approach found on this website:

https://fabriceleven.com/design/creating-fancy-css3-fade-in-animations-on-page-load/

Answer (score 1):

A solution without javascript: Have the 5 elements remain unchanging. Then have a single element (I'll use the pseudo `:after` element) which moves to cover each in turn, and as it is covering it briefly illuminates.

```js
// No javascript needed! :D
```

```css
@keyframes moving-light {
  0% { margin-left: 1%; }
  80% { margin-left: 81%; }
  100% { margin-left: 81%; }
}
@keyframes blinking-light {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  65% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.lightup {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; height: 30px;
  font-size: 0; /* Get rid of any inline spaces between elements */
}
.lightup > .box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18%; height: 100%;
  margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%;
  background-color: #a00000;
}
.lightup:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 18%; height: 100%;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  background-color: #ff4040;
  opacity: 1;
  
  animation:
    5s steps(4, end) infinite moving-light,
    1s ease-out infinite blinking-light;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightup">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTimeout function to delay something

//delay by 500ms

```
setTimeout( do_something_here, 500);
```

Comment: setTimeout Is not a JQuery function. It is a function that comes by default in the browser

Comment: `setTimeout` is not jQuery's.

Comment: Ah my mistake..but still, you can use it with jquery

Comment: The issue isn't really literally how to delay, but how to rewrite my javascript so that there is a place to put the code to delay.

Answer (score 0):

Give all divs a common class like `skills` Then call a .each on them with a 500 ms delay.

The jQuery function should look something like this:

```
$('.skills').each(function(){
   setTimeout( $(this).removeClass('skill-rank-inactive'),500);
)}
```

Call this function on `document.ready()` or on an event.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a loop with setTimeout()

```
$('#skills-page').bind('inview', function() {

    var delay = 0;

   $.each( $('.skill-rank-inactive'), function(){
        var element = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            element.addClass('skill-rank-active')
            element.removeClass('skill-rank-inactive');
        },delay);

        delay += 500;
    });

});
```

I know that setTimeout is not jquery but the question has been:

> "Is there a way to add 500ms delay between the transition of each
>   "skill-rank" on the page?"